# Create a color scale with css using a range

Tags: css, coldfusion

I have a numeric range that goes from 0 to 311 to 351, is there a way in css to make a scale that moves with it, starting red, transitioning to yellow on the 311 and then from yellow to green on 311 to 351?

I need a given color at a given point on the scale, not the full scale; so what I'm wondering is can I make a color in css that is some % red, some % yellow, some % green?

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a `linear-gradient` - 311/351 * 100 = 88.6%, so the gradient will be from red 0% to yellow 88.6% to green at 100%:

```css
.scale {
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, yellow 88.6%, green 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="scale"></div>
```

Comment: That does answer my question, thank you. Is there any way to "pick up" the color code from a shade at a certain point along the scale?

Comment: You'll have to draw the gradient with canvas, and then you can pick the color at every single point.

Answer (score 2):

Are you attempting to style table column cells and using jQuery? If so, HeatColor is a easy plugin to integrate and has lots of options.
https://github.com/joshuanathanson/jquery-heatcolor

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I've searched, found his repository and have updated the link.